Is there a formula to copy data from one database to another in SQL?
During some work in SQL I needed a formula to be able to transport a series of data from one database to another in order to join the data and work together.
The problem that was encountered is due to the fact that I don't know if it can use a formula similar to CONCATENATE that is used in spreadsheets. I tried using CONCAT but since I'm not an expert I couldn't write code that would do my job.

Any solution is likely to be RDBMS-specific so please tag your question with the RDBMS you are using. Also, update your question with sample data and the result you want to achieve - all as editable text, appropriately formatted

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
